# How can I draw / type something like this with Latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image: elementary level math]

How can I draw something like this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this intended to be a table? Should the vertical lines on rows be a single straight line?

Comment: @Vincent I don't know, actually, I am very new to Latex, I am using Latex for teaching online, and this is how we teach our students to calculate GCD on white board during class. This can be table or just vertical and horizontal line, but I am looking for some easy way / command so numbers are aligned correctly. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something like this that you're looking for?
[image: table?]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|l}
        2 & 16, 32, 72 \\
        \cline{2-2}
        2 & 8, 16, 36 \\
        \cline{2-2}
        2 & 4, 8, 18 \\
        \cline{2-2}
        2 & 2, 4, 9 \\
        \cline{2-2}
        2 & 1, 2, 9 \\
        \cline{2-2} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it solves my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could also easily add the commas automatically and align the numbers in columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|r@{, }r@{, }r}
2 & 16 & 32 & 72 \\ \cline{2-4}
2 &  8 & 16 & 36 \\ \cline{2-4}
2 &  4 &  8 & 18 \\ \cline{2-4}
2 &  2 &  4 &  9 \\ \cline{2-4}
  &  1 &  2 &  9 \\ \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, I hesitated to propose this as a solution in the first place.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks ... power of the community expertise. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Recently wanted about the same thing. Using soul package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\setuloverlap{-1.25pt}
\vspace{6pt}
\centerline{10\ul{|372}\hspace{1em}Remainder}
\centerline{\hspace{-3.75em}10\ul{|37}\hspace{1em}2}
\centerline{\hspace{-3.25em}10\ul{)3}\hspace{1em}7}
\centerline{\hspace{-1.75em}0\hspace{1em}3}
\vspace{1pt}
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image]